LINQ returning null for some xml read
My xml read with linq used to work great, but I recently changed my xml (the team wanted flatter xml), and the format is like this now:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerficationRoot>
<Configuration>
    <Value Name="emailFrom">us@co.com</Value>
    <Value Name="admin_list">me@co.com</Value> 
    <Value Name="distribution_list">me@co.com</Value> 
    <Value Name="SmtpMailClient">info.co.net</Value>
    <Value Name="verboseLogFileName">VerifyBuildVerbose.txt</Value>
    <Value Name="statsLogProcessVerFileName">Stats.txt</Value>
    <Value Name="project">proj</Value>
    <Value Name="version">1.0</Value>
</Configuration>
<BuildVerification>
    <codeFreezeTime>19:00</codeFreezeTime>
    <build machine="mach-31">
            <Process name="log1"
                startTimeHeader="StartTime"
                endTimeHeader="EndTime"
                failureColumns="ErrorDescription">
                    <Condition
                        name='VersionFile' value="\view\proj\filename.cs">
                    </Condition>
                    <SuccessCriteria>
                        <field>Status</field>
                        <comparison>equal</comparison> 
                        <value>Success</value>
                    </SuccessCriteria>
            </Process>
            <!-- we get multiple processes under each build machine and
                 there are multiple build machines with processes under them. -->
     </build>
    
</BuildVerification>

I'm trying to modify my LINQ that reads this xml file.  There are multiple conditions for some processes to read into my list.  Also, there are multiple success criteria in some cases to go into it's list.
This is what I have right now for the LINQ:
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string newPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\.."));
string finalPathXmlb = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(newPath, configFileName));
XDocument xmlDoc2 = XDocument.Load(finalPathXmlb);
var results1 =
xmlDoc2.Descendants("BuildVerification")
.SelectMany(a => a.Descendants("build")
.SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
.Select(p => new ProcessValidationInfo
{
    codeFreezeTime = b.Parent.Element("codeFreezeTime")?.Value,
    buildMach = a.Element("machine")?.Value,
    p1 = p.Element("name")?.Value,
    startTimeHeader = p.Element("startTimeHeader")?.Value,
    endTimeHeader = p.Element("endTimeHeader")?.Value,
    failureColumns = p.Element("failureColumns")?.Value,
    conditionList = p.Descendants("Condition")
        .Select(c => new Condition
        {
            cName = c.Attribute("name")?.Value,
            cValue = c.Attribute("value")?.Value,
            cValueAlternate = c.Attribute("alternateValue")?.Value
        })
        .ToList(),
    successCriteriaList = p.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
        .Select(sc => new SuccessCriteria
        {
            f1 = sc.Element("field")?.Value,
            c1 = sc.Element("comparison")?.Value,
            v1 = sc.Element("value")?.Value,
            alt_v1 = sc.Element("alternateValue")?.Value
        })
        .ToList()
}))).ToList();

But right now there are several values that are null.  I tried modifying the linq to get the missing info, but it's still null.
Problem: buildMach, endTimeheader, startTimeHeader, failureColumns, and p1 is null in the results.
I was looking at linq returning null, which seems similar, but I tried changing my Linq to use BuildVerification (used to have build for descendants part) for the xmlDoc2.Descendants part, but it didn't fix anything.
The conditions and success criteria are reading into their lists fine currently.
For more info on this, like classes storing xml, see classes storing xml.

Try Descendants : p.Descendants("startTimeHeader").FirstOrDefault().Value  My preference is following : (string)p.Descendants("startTimeHeader").FirstOrDefault()  Using Value can give error when null.  Casting will not give the error.

@jdweng I tried changing the line to startTimeHeader = (string)p.Descendants("startTimeHeader").FirstOrDefault()?.Value, and it's still null

I think it's because the build isn't a tag alone now, it's surrounding the attributes inside it.

The chained LINQ calls are operating on the output of the prior function. It is not nested loops. .SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process") returns a collection of Process elements.  The .Select(p => ...) operates on the Process element collection. Within the lambda expression, write everything in terms of p. e.g. codeFreezeTime = p.Parent.Parent.Element("codeFreezeTime")?.Value,.

You can try buildMach = a.Attribute("machine")?.Value, etc.

Given that a Process element is only ever a /BuildVerficationRoot/BuildVerification/build/Process, the code can be xmlDoc2.Descendants("Process").Select(p => ...

@YitzhakKhabinsky tat buildmach line suggestion still shows buildMach as null when I run it.

@JonathanDodds I'm trying xmlDoc2.descendants("Process") , and yes codeFreeezeTime=p.Parent.Parent.Element("codeFreezeTime")?.Value still works, but p1=p.Parent.Element("name")?.Value is still null, and so is buildMach=p.parent.Element("machine")?.Value

thanks for all of the ideas! I think I'm starting to understand this.

Oh, I missed it before but "name", "startTimeHeader", and "endTimeHeader" are attributes, not elements. p.Parent.Attribute("name")

@JonathanDodds with testing, it looks like using Process in Descendants and.Select  p=>new ProcessValidationInfo, that the name is found with p.Attribute("name").Value, without parent.  Buildmach needed the parent though.

It looks like this is working...
var results1 =
xmlDoc2.Descendants("Process")
.Select(p => new ProcessValidationInfo
{
    codeFreezeTime = p.Parent.Parent.Element("codeFreezeTime")?.Value,
    buildMach = p.Parent.Attribute("machine")?.Value,
    p1 = p.Attribute("name")?.Value,
    startTimeHeader = (string)p.Attribute("startTimeHeader")?.Value,
    endTimeHeader = p.Attribute("endTimeHeader")?.Value,
    failureColumns = p.Attribute("failureColumns")?.Value,
    conditionList = p.Descendants("Condition")
        .Select(c => new Condition
        {
            cName = c.Attribute("name")?.Value,
            cValue = c.Attribute("value")?.Value,
            cValueAlternate = c.Attribute("alternateValue")?.Value
        })
        .ToList(),
    successCriteriaList = p.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
        .Select(sc => new SuccessCriteria
        {
            f1 = sc.Element("field")?.Value,
            c1 = sc.Element("comparison")?.Value,
            v1 = sc.Element("value")?.Value,
            alt_v1 = sc.Element("alternateValue")?.Value
        })
        .ToList()
}).ToList();

